# EF Code First Database Migrations - how to exclude a column from being migrated?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration

I have a class from which I use Database Migrations to update a corresponding table.
However there is a field I want to put into the classes that should not get migrated to the database.

Is there an attribute I can use to do this?

Something like

```
[IgnoreColumn]
public bool Selected { get; set; }
```

Ignore ONLY for database updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore properties:

```
     modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().Ignore(p=>p.foobar);
```